# html/php not uploading files

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have looked all over stackoverflow and have not yet found a working answer.
The HTML form allows the user to upload multiple files using one single input, the values then travel to a php file (named upload.php) to be uploaded to their final resting place.... this doesn't happen.

My HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Files" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"/>
</form>
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php
if(count($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {  
    foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $file) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], './uploads/'.$_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
    }  
}  
?>
```

Comment: what error you are facing now in php?

Comment: @Hardik I don't see any visual errors, just the files don't seem to be passing through move_uploaded_file() - they're not appearing in the uploads folder.

Comment: Is your file path is correct ?

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: what you are getting in var_dump($_FILES[]);

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/hty39slr/public_html/photos/upload.php on line 10

Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/hty39slr/public_html/photos/upload.php on line 10

Comment: @Hardik yes my path is correct. it may be something to do with the Array as when I change it to move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][0], './uploads/'.$_FILES["upload"]["name"][0]); it uploades the first file; move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][1], './uploads/'.$_FILES["upload"]["name"][1]); uploads the second file and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Files" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"/>
</form>
```

Your PHP file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {  
        foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $key=>$file) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], './uploads/'.$file);
        }  
    } 

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I never really know how to use foreach loops but I should probably start learning.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this answer and below code is working for me.... hope this will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<body>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Files" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"/>
</form>
<div>
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $key=>$filename){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$key], '.pathtoupload/'.$filename);
    }
 }?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/hty39slr/public_html/photos/upload.php on line 8

Comment: you have literally just copied the answer which i marked as working.

Comment: Hahaha, it's just minutes difference otherwise you were accept my answer.